# Netty Verify on runtime, NioEventLoopGroup

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, netty

I have been debugging my environment with additions and all of a sudden I received a Verify error with Netty.

The version of Netty is 4.1.46.Final, Java JDK version is 11 compile and runtime.

I use Guice but it does nothing with the netty portion aside from initializing this class, I also have had this error on another project setup a while back where I was not using Guice whatsoever.

I have tried invalidating caches/restarting, -U with maven to update my dependencies, uninstalling intellij even, as well as -noverify does nothing.

My code:

```kotlin
class LoginService @Inject constructor() : AbstractIdleService()
{

    private lateinit var bootstrap : ServerBootstrap

    @Inject private lateinit var configuration: RSEEnvironment

    @Inject private lateinit var channelHandler: LoginChannelHandler

    private val bossGroup = NioEventLoopGroup(1)

    private val workerGroup = NioEventLoopGroup(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())

    private lateinit var future: ChannelFuture

    override fun startUp()
    {

        val hostAddress = configuration.getString("default_host")

        val hostPort = configuration.getInt("default_port")

        bootstrap = ServerBootstrap()

        bootstrap
            .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel::class.java)
            .childHandler(channelHandler)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)

        future = bootstrap.bind(hostAddress, hostPort).syncUninterruptibly()

        future.channel().closeFuture().sync()

    }

    override fun shutDown()
    {

        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully()

    }

    @Provides fun fetchEnvironment() = RSEEnvironment()

}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop overrides final method io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.pendingTasks()I
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:145)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:52)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:96)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:91)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:52)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:44)
    at rs.emulator.service.login.LoginService.<init>(LoginService.kt:25)
    at rs.emulator.service.login.LoginService$$FastClassByGuice$$f37422b6.newInstance(<generated>)
```

---------- update ---------

If I create another module in my project and do just the basic code it works fine on the same maven parent.

Comment: Temporary fix: If I remove the dependency from my parent pom and add it to the modules pom it works, for now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a class path issue. Seems to me that you have multiple version of netty on the class path. Ensure you only have one.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct, I was using a dependency that used an older version of netty and didn't realize the netty-buffer was out of date.